# How do I run a meteor.js app using 0.8.0-rc1?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to run my meteor.js app using the latest 0.8.0-rc1 build. How do I update my app to run with 0.8.0-rc1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current release is 0.8.0-rc3 (2014-03-26). You can update your app by running `meteor update --release 0.8.0-rc3` in the app root directory.

Additionally, here are two great resources for running a Meteor.js app on blaze (0.8.0)
http://meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Comment: You can also try it out without changing the default like this: `meteor --release 0.8.0-rc3`

Comment: Just for you folks that come across this late. Meteor has officially updated to 0.8.0. Check out the docs. http://docs.meteor.com